# Alternate row color except 'no-alternate-color' class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this expression in a JavaScript file...

```
$('tbody tr:even').addClass("alt-row");
```

It alternates the color of all my table rows, which is ok. But I would like to add an exception class such as "no-alternate-color" to the tr's.

```
<table id="invoice">
  <tbody>
  <tr class="headings">
    <th class="item first" style="padding-left:5px;">Unidad</th>
    <th class="description">Descripcion</th>
    <th class="price">Precio</th>
    <th class="quantity">Cantidad</th>
    <th class="linetotal last" style="padding-right:7px;">Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lineitem alt-row" style="border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5;">
    <td class="item_name_data" style="padding:2px 2px 2px 5px;">MacBook Pro 13"</td>
    <td class="description">13-inch: 2.4 GHz
2.4GHz dual-core
Intel Core i5
    </td>
    <td class="price_data">1199.99</td>
    <td class="quantity_data">2</td>
    <td class="linetotal_data" style="padding-right:5px;">2399.98</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lineitem" style="border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5;">
    <td class="item_name_data" style="padding:2px 2px 2px 5px;">Muji Table</td>
    <td class="description">awesome light brown table</td>
    <td class="price_data">89.99</td>
    <td class="quantity_data">1</td>
    <td class="linetotal_data" style="padding-right:5px;">89.99</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

For example, the table above did not originally had the "alt-row" class in the tr's, but it was added by the jQuery function.

I'm not very fluent with jQuery. How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with CSS alone if you'd like (depending on what you are trying to accomplish).. something to this effect..

http://jsfiddle.net/xENWM/1/

Comment: @milkywayjoe In case you didn't notice, there is a slight difference in the result of the two approaches.  The jquery way takes the `no-alt` rows completely out of the calculation of what is odd and what is even, the css just skips the evens that are of the class.  Fiddle to see the difference http://jsfiddle.net/xENWM/3/  nto sure if it matters to you.

Comment: I see that there's a small diff but overall, for what I might use something like this, I like the css better.. both solutions are good tho

Answer (score 5):

```
$('tbody tr:not(.no-alternate-color):even').addClass("alt-row");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CKeew/

Comment: This one does it, and super simple

Comment: I wasn't able to find a reference in a quick search, but I recall running into significant performance problems with the :not selector in IE; if that's a problem for you can try using the .not function instead:  $('tbody tr').not('.no-alternate-color').filter(':even').addClass('alt-row')